# Flutter remove extra white space between string

Tags: string, flutter, split

how to remove extra white space between following string ?
String word= "Hai     where  are    you    from" ;
word.split(" ") does not work for this condition.

Comment: the `word` is normally spaced. what do you mean by extra whitespace?.

Comment: @SuzZan there were two spaces between each words. But it reduced to single space when i paste the content here. I found the solution . Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove extra white spaces you can use this code. Just call the `cleanupWhitespace` method and it will return the cleaned up string.

```
final whitespaceRE = RegExp(r"(?! )\s+| \s+");
String cleanupWhitespace(String input) => input.split(whitespaceRE).join(" ");
```

It works like this for ex if you have a string like this:

```
Hello                   world
```

It will replace all the white space with a single white space.

```
Hello world
```

Answer (score 2):

You can you two functions for String:
ReplaceAll Function

```
String str;
  str.replaceAll(" ", " ");
```

Trim function

```
str.trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

this will remove the white space in the string

try

```
String word= "Hai where are you from";
print(word.replaceAll(' ', ''));
```